# How to correctly use a Picker and a BrowserComponent on the same form?

Tags: java, codenameone, picker

I need to use both a **Picker** and a **BrowserComponent** on the same form.

The **Picker** will allow the user to select a value used to produce the HTML that will be displayed by the **BrowserComponent**.

The following code works nice on Android.

On iOS, after the Picker has been used to select a value, all gets messed up : the picker remains drawn on screen, the BrowserComponent is empty and the app hangs !?

A bug in Codename One ?

The problem is reproductible on iOS 10, 10.3.3 and 12.1

```
package edu.ch.emf.praesto;

import static com.codename1.ui.CN.*;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent;
import com.codename1.ui.CN1Constants;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.spinner.Picker;

public class App {

    private Form currentForm;
    private Resources theme;

    public void init(Object context) {
        // Loading the theme
        this.theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");
    }

    public void start() {

        // Load last shown form on reopening
        if (this.currentForm != null) {
            this.currentForm.show();
            return;
        }

        // Force orientation locking if the plattform supports it
        if (Display.getInstance().canForceOrientation()) {
            Display.getInstance().lockOrientation(true);
        }

        Form form = new Form(new BorderLayout());

        String[] strs = new String[]{"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"};

        Picker picker = new Picker();
        picker.setType(CN1Constants.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
        picker.setStrings(strs);
        form.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, picker);

        BrowserComponent htmlViewer = new BrowserComponent();
        htmlViewer.setPage("<html><head></head><body><h1>Test</h1></body></html>", null);
        form.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, htmlViewer);

        form.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.currentForm = getCurrentForm();
        if (this.currentForm instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog) this.currentForm).dispose();
            this.currentForm = getCurrentForm();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Picker.setDefaultUseLightweightPopup(true)` to force the picker to use the Java rendered implementation instead of the flaky implementation from iOS.

Unfortunately, this might make the picker on Android behave like the iOS picker which isn't optimal for all cases. So you can try excluding Android from this logic.